# Why do I get the 'unable to create .../.hg/record-backups' when trying to commit in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, commit

Has anyone seen this before? Thanks.

Using Mercurial 1.7.5 with TortoiseHg on Windows Vista Service Pack 1.

Comment: You should explain your problem better. What version of mercurial are you using, what is the os, did it work earlier, etc

Answer (score 1):

If this is with TortoiseHg, the [`commit.py`](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/src/ef5ab6bccf5e/hggtk/commit.py) seems to ties this error strictly with an os operation

```python
  backupdir = repo.join('record-backups')
    try:
        os.mkdir(backupdir)
    except OSError, err:
        if err.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            Prompt('Commit', 'Unable to create ' + backupdir,
                    self).run()
            return
```

So there must be some kind of ACL issue (right access).

Comment: I was committing from TortoiseHg. I tried to commit from the commandline and discovered that it was the file name that was too long.

Comment: @Geoffrey: so it was an os-related issue, then? As illustrated by the TortoiseHg code extract I mention?